# How to create error based on Lookup value in Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have Azure Data Factory pipeline.
After processing data, I would like to validate from Azure SQL database to catch exception, which were not catched by data factory. There are situations were no new rows were created because of errors in system.

So I would create Lookup to make SELECT COUNT statement to check specific ID exists or not.
Value 0 would mean that no required row is created and error should occur in data factory.

How to create error for monitoring data factory if lookup value is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **lookup the sql sink** with query to count the rows in it. Then use `IfCondition` activity to compare the result with `0` and proceed with any action as necessary.

Query: `SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[myStudents]`

IfActivityExpression: `@equals(activity('Lookup SQL').output.value,0)`

[image]